# How to change log level for slack jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have slack jenkins plugin installed on my machine and it's working well, besides the fact that there are many INFO log message that booming my log.
is there any way to change the log level of slack plugin ?
does something like : `jenkins.plugins.slack=ERROR` would work ? does the slack plugin supports it?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is equipped with a GUI for configuring/collecting/reporting log records of your choosing. This page shows you how to do this.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging